# Parse.com Check if column row is blank/empty and then delete the whole row

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Here is my Parse.com page:
[image]

What i want, is that when the application starts, it checks in the "currentUpload", if imageFile has any (undefined) or empty rows.(Where there is no "uploaded_image.png", and if there are a empty row, delete the empty row. So i want to delete the rows that does NOT contains "uploaded_image.png" only.

Any ideas? Hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `notExist`:

```
query.whereKeyDoesNotExist("imageFile")
query.limit = 1000
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { objects, error in
    if error == nil {
        PBObject.deleteAllInBackground(objects)
    }
}
```

You'll have to set something up that checks if more exist, since you'll only be able to delete 1000 at a time.

I recommend you set this up as a server job as opposed to doing it client side if you're feeling up to it!